# Modificar un archivo usando android studio

Tags: java, android

necesito modificar el archivo que os muestro a continuación:

[image: Imagen localización del archivo]

He probado de varias formas pero siempre me sale error. Os dejo el siguiente código para saber en que estoy fallando. Muchas gracias.

```
try{
    FileOutputStream archivo= new FileOutputStream("assets/prueba.json",true);
    archivo.write("hola".getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El directorio Assets es de solo lectura, así que no vas a poder escribir en él, pero siempre puedes usar un fichero interno haciendo algo parecido a:

```
String FILENAME = "prueba.json";
String string = "Esta es mi prueba";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Puedes encontrar más info del tema en la guía de developers de Android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me ha servido.